# minimization and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $a$ and $b$ be $\mathbb{R}$ numbers and define
>   $$
> D=(a-b-3)^2+(a-1)^2+(a+b+1)^2+(a+2b+2)^2
> $$
>
> 1)
>   Define a vector $y=(3,1,-1,-2)$
>
> Find a $4 \times 2$ matrix A, such that $D=||A(a,b)-y||^2$
>
> 2)
>   Solve the equation $A^TA(a,b)=A^Ty$
>
> 3) Find the vector $(a,b)$ which makes $D$ as small as possible.

**Questions**

1)

I am not sure how to find the 4 x 2 matrix. I simplified $D=4a^2+4ab-2a+6b^2+16b+15$. I'm uncertain how to proceed and if I am right in simplifying D.

2)

I'm fairly certain I know how to do this. But I havn't done it yet as I don't know matrix A.

3)

I assume this is a vector $(a,b)$ such that $||A(a,b)-y||^2$ is as small as possible. Could this be a null vector $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: Is $A^TA(a,b)=A^Ty$ a ODE???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding $1)$: Note that $\Vert (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \Vert ^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+ x_n^2$

Regarding $2)$: You probably mean *linear system of equations*? Try to argue that $A^t A$ is invertible and calculate $(a,b)^t  = (A^tA)^{-1} A^t y$

Regarding $3)$: Search for *Gaussian normal equation* and you will see that $(a,b)^t$ that we got from $2)$ exactly minimizes $D$.